# How to find out the noise level of a signal

Tags: noise, snr, self-study

Is it possible to find the amount of noise or SNR of a signal from its time series output? For example; let `x = randn(100,1)`  and `y = awgn(signal,-5,'measured');` be two signals. Here `signal` is an unknown source signal of length 10,000 data points.

In Matlab this is what I did: `snr(x)` = 0.5177 and  `snr(y) = -34.3797 dB` Shouldn't I get `-5 dB` as SNR?

I am unable to understand what these values convey as they are a ratio: How is 0.5177 coming? Since I am generating `y` with an SNR of -5 dB, so `snr(y)` should be -5 dB.  Please help in clarifying if these answers are right and how to make sense of it.

Comment: Try reading the MATLAB docs: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/snr.html. Then you’ll understand if you want $-5$ dB to be the answer then you should do ```snr(y, noise)```

Comment: Thank you! What is the correct way to call `y`? Can I say `y` is a noise corrupted signal at SNR = -5 dB?

Comment: Yeah I'm assuming that ```y = signal + noise```

Comment: Ok, but about `x` signal which is not added with any other signal. How do I find out its noise or SNR level?

Comment: I thought ```x``` is the noise-less signal...you're saying that ```x``` has noise added to it too?

Comment: If you have the original signal without noise, and then the signal together with the noise and you want to know how to get the SNR from these two sequences, this has already been answered. I will link it. Please let me know if this is not what you are asking for.

Comment: I have two signals: `x` which is noiseless and `y` which is noisy. The answer related to `y` is  clear to me. But how to find for the original signal without noise, which is `x` in my case has not been answered, or if it is then I did not follow. Trying to know if `x` which is the noise free signal has any SNR or noise level to it. Is it `snr(x) = 0.5177 dB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just don't think you're thinking this through all the way, and using the toolbox in MATLAB before you understand the basics. SNR is signal-to-noise ratio and is defined as $\text{SNR}=\frac{\text{Signal Power}}{\text{Noise Power}}$. When you call `snr(signal, noise)` in MATLAB, all it is doing is calculating the signal power, `mean(abs(signal).^2)`, and the noise power, `mean(abs(noise).^2)`, taking the ratio of them and returning the result in decibels (dB).

In the comments you are asking about how to calculate the SNR of `x` (the noiseless signal)...well its dividing by zero because the noise power in a noiseless signal is zero. You'd be doing $\frac{\text{Signal Power}}{0}=\infty$, you can go ahead and try using the `snr` function by doing `snr(signal, zeros(size(signal)))` but I'm willing to bet it either returns `Inf` or gives an error.

Note: Read the MATLAB docs on `snr(signal)` and you'll realize it is probably not returning what you expect. Docs are here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/snr.html